# jQuery UI Datepicker - Combining 2 Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a working function which disables all Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays and Thursdays. It looks like this:

```
$("#dateInput").datepicker({
    minDate: 2,
    maxDate: "+3M",
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: function(day) {
        var day = day.getDay();
        if (day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4) {
            return [false, ""]
        }
        else {
            return [true, ""]
        }
    }
});
```

Now what I need is to also be able to disable specific dates, for example October 25th. I found a function which works on it's own:

```
$("#dateInput").datepicker({
    minDate: 2,
    maxDate: "+3M",
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: disableAllTheseDays,
});

var disabledDays = ["10-25-2013"];
function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
 var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }
}
return [true];
}
```

But I don't know how to combine it with the existing Monday to Thursday function I have. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy demo at http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/E9m8G/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 2,
    maxDate: "+3M",
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: function(day) {
        var newday = day.getDay();
        if (newday == 1 || newday == 2 || newday == 3 || newday == 4) {
            return [false, ""]
        }
        else {
            var disabledDays = ["10-25-2013"];        
        var m = day.getMonth(), d = day.getDate(), y = day.getFullYear();
for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }
}
return [true];
    }
        }


});
  });
```